# Is it possible to use more than one native query for returning a resultset in a java object

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, nativequery

I've been looking everywhere and I cannot find a question similar to mine.
But what I've been wondering is say I make a object that will be used for a result set, I have queries that I'd like to run and grab the data and place it into my object, but I will need to run more than one query.
I had in mind to use native queries but I don't know if it's possible to be able to use more than one in an object.

E.g. I have an object with variables and that need to be placed from the native query, and then another query which could retrieve the amount of the fields and also save it into a variable inside of the same object, but the issue is it'd need a different query, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the two queries individually and aggregate the results into an object of your choice. Hibernate allows to aggregate data from different tables through joins and also through `@Formula` which could make use of subqueries, but using subqueries in entities is rarely advisable.

Without more context it's hard to give you a recommendation. Maybe share the queries with use or the object model you are trying to fill so that we can imagine what your intent is.

Comment: At the moment I cannot since the queries aren't mine, but could you give me an example of this? Also the best example I could give is I have an object that has 3 fields, two of which is the result set of one query, and the third I'd need to run another query to get that information, I've seen how you can use native queries to be able to save the result table info into a java object without it having to be tied to a specific entity, I just wondered if it's also possible to use more than one native query when one has already been declared it in the java object

Comment: What's the issue? Just call setters or pass constructor arguments to get the desired target object from the data you have. That's a simple transformation.